# List of Object as parameter of IN operator

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm doing a migration of jpa provider from Eclipselink 2.4.2 to Hibernate 4.3.5.

I'd like to pass a list of objects as parameter of IN operator. Currently, I'm trying to use a `List<UUID>` but it also fails with a `List<Class<?>>`.

My query looks like :

```
SELECT e
FROM Entity e
WHERE e.uuid IN :uuids;
```

The code :

```
List<UUID> uuids = new ArrayList<UUID>();
uuids.add(UUID.fromString("..."));

Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
query.setParameter("uuids", uuids);

List list = query.list(); // <-- fails here
```

The exception with `List<UUID>` :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.UUID
```

And with `UUID[]` :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.util.UUID; cannot be cast to java.util.UUID
```

Hibernate seems not to understand correctly this kind of list. When debugging, I can see that the `QueryLoader` use the correct descriptor but doesn't translate it as list.

Actually, this was working with Eclipselink. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `SELECT e
FROM Entity e
WHERE e.uuid IN (:uuids);` IN clause requires bracket, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but brackets are not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using `query.setParameter(..)` (instead of `session.setParaemter(..)` as stated in your code example.

For multiple values of a named query, you should use `setParameterList` instead of `setParameter`:

```
List<UUID> uuids = new ArrayList<UUID>();
uuids.add(UUID.fromString("..."));

Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
// **This method setParameterList bind multiple values to a named query parameter.**
query.setParameterList("uuids", uuids);

List list = query.list();
```

Comment: Just updated my question. I think `setParameterList` will work, I just read it in another site. Going to test!

Comment: I was also missing the `setParameterList`
Thanks